# Problem modelling a simple shape and then applying subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

I am trying to model a shape like this in Blender:

[image]

I have made several attempts, but having problems each time when applying a final subdivision surface modifier, so would appreciate some guidance.

My first attempt was to follow my instinct and create a 2D arrangement of vertices (a quarter circle which is then turned into the final shape), which is then extruded. The subdivision (right-most image) looks incorrect:

[image]

My next attempt was to try creating a cuboid and a cylinder, and then performing a ***<kbd>Difference</kbd>*** Boolean operation to obtain the mesh, but this results in the same final mesh as above (and therefore a messed-up subdivision modifier version):

[image]

I had some success when trying to add extra edge loops, to try to control the shape more, but there are strange "creases" appearing in the mesh:

[image]

Finally, after reading a little, it seems to be preferable when modelling to keep all your faces as "quads" (i.e. four vertices to each face). It's clear that with my attempts above that this is not the case, so I tried a version which was made of only quads, using the knife tool to draw the extra straight lines. This results in a messed-up final subdivided mesh again:

[image]

Is there an easy solution to this, or am I approaching the meshing process in the wrong way? I am a complete Blender beginner, so maybe I'm just misunderstanding how to do it?

---

**Edit**

After reading some of the answers, it seems like this shape can be modelled with the top face of the mesh being either an N-gon (as in my original image), a collection of quad faces, or a collection of triangular faces (as in the answers of Yousuf Chaudhry and moonboots). Any comments on the pros/cons of these 3 approaches would be useful for me.

Comment: in the last step, did you try selecting all and merging by distance?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry, yes I have tried that several times. I'm just not sure the "most sensible" way to approach these sorts of modelling shapes generally

Comment: I tried using quads, and it works, though it took some time

Comment: Did you try using a bevel before the subsurface instead of adding edge loops?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I intentionally avoided the Bevel tool, because I saw several tutorials that say it's better to use Edge Loops + Subdivision Surface Modifier, because it allows to change the degree to which the edges are rounded at a later time (not easy once the bevel was applied). My version using only quads didnt work, as shown above. I was also suspicious about this approach because it also took me a long time, which I thought cant be right to model such a simple shape

Comment: Not the bevel tool, the bevel modifier

Comment: and yes you are right about taking so much time, to be honest I have never encountered this problem before myself. I'll try to find a quick solution

Comment: Oh and make sure your scale is applied.

Comment: I think Allen's answer is the best. It never occurred to me. But the con is you absolutely need the bevel modifier. My con is that triangles are formed, but that could be solved by Faces > Tris to Quads. Moonboots also has a great answer, though the con is you have to manually fix the geometry.

Comment: Just one thing, referring to your "it seems to be preferable when modelling to keep all your faces as quads": it's simply not true. There are times where you should use quads, but there are also models where ngons are okay or sometimes even better. As so often in life, it really depends on what your goals are, how you want to further edit the meshes or what modifiers you use on them. I cannot explain every aspect of it, but Josh Gambrell has a good video on why ngons are sometimes preferable: [Why ngons are BETTER than quads for hard surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svS9V2iAesA)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Useful to know, thanks for the advice and the link - I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Bevel Modifier* with *Shape* set to 1 and two *Segments* will keep the original shape intact while adding quad faces around everything.  This will make the following *Subdivision Surface* modifier behave better.

[image]

Example of topology leftover by *Bevel* modifier.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use this topology, you can use tris if it doesn't create artefacts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, suddenly, three answers pop out of nowhere ^_^

Comment: Thanks, can you show how you created this? (I.e, once the curved face is made, how do you add the extra edges and make them all meet at the single point). Do you then use the Knife tool to draw the extra edges across the rest of the shape?

Comment: As Yousuf says, bevel a vertex (Ctrl B then V), in the Operator box choose a Shape value of 0.1, cut the edges with the knife tool, extrude up, select the edges you want to sharpen, bevel

Comment: What settings are you using for your final bevel (segments, and shape)?

Comment: 2 szgments and the shape is probably 0.5

Comment: Thanks, it works. I guess I am confused about how to approach it. If we apply a final bevel at the end (or even indeed bevel modifier) then it doesn't seem to matter if we use your approach (made up of triangle faces) or Yousuf's approach (made of a single N-gon face). To add to the confusion, both are different from the "advice" I have read elsewhere which recommends aiming for quads. Should I be aiming for something in particular when modelling things like this, or it's just a case of whatever works is fine? For example, your solution has many extra edges, adding more complication...

Comment: @teeeeee It's always whatever is fastest and works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I just got the simplest answer ever.

Just take a plane, select one of the corner vertices, and bevel it, with it set to *Vertices* (Or you could just use a boolean):

[image]

Then, delete the face by pressing `X` > `Faces Only`. Then go to *Faces* > `Grid fill` and set the offset set to `3`.

Then joust use a solidify modifier to extrude, add a bevel "modifier" to easily compensate for the edge loops, and add a subdivision surface and you have it!

[image]

Comment: After deleting the face as you said, when I try to choose Face->Grid Fill I get the error message "Select two edge loops or a single closed edge loop from which two edge loops can be calculated". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Okay I have it now - it seems like it matters which two edges you select before applying the Grid Fill.

Comment: Your approach results in several triangular faces on the mesh after Grid Fill is applied. Do you have an opinion on why this is more preferable than Allen Simpson's answer above? (which treats the face as a single N-gon, like I did in my original post, but then simply adds a bevel modifier). Thanks

Comment: @teeeeee not at all, just a different solution

Comment: The answer was supposed to be posted hours ago, but it got posted late

Comment: So there a little confusion in the phrasing ;)